# Embed Javascript file in an XSL File

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have an xsl file, that generates a link "Preview".

```
  <a>
       <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:text>#preview</xsl:text>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
           <xsl:text>embeddedPreview("</xsl:text>
           <xsl:text>http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=</xsl:text>
           <!--Google can't reach a local development machines, so you may want to code in your production server, where Google downloads the file from-->
           <!--<xsl:text>http://example.edu/</xsl:text>-->
           <!-- Getting bitstreams by ID  XMLUI: /xmlui/bitstream/id  JSPUI: /jspui/retrieve -->
           <xsl:text>/xmlui/bitstream/id/</xsl:text>       
           <xsl:value-of select="substring(@ID,6)"/>
           <xsl:text>&amp;embedded=true</xsl:text>
           <xsl:text>");</xsl:text>
       /xsl:attribute>
           Preview
   </a>
```

Whenever the link is click, the onclick event calls a javascript function called embeddedPreview. embeddedPreview function is stored in mylibrary.js:

```
/**
 * Creates an iframe with the specified source
 * @REQUIRES jQuery
 * @REQUIRES that there exists an element with ID preview-embed
 */
function embeddedPreview(source) {
    if($("#embed").length > 0) {
        //set the source to the location asked for
        $("#embed").attr("http://19.46.1.34:8081/xmlui/handle/123456789", source);
    } else {
        //Create the embed iframe
        $("#preview-embed").append("<iframe id='embed' src='"+source+"' width='100%' height='342px' style='border:none;'/>"); //requires jQuery
    }
}
```

Whenever I click the Preview link, an error occurs saying:

```
UnCaughtReferenceError: embeddedPreview is not defined
onclick
```

How to embed Javascript in an XSL file?

Comment: did my answer helped ? have you ever got this to works ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the XSLT, because the error given specify that `embeddedPreview` was called, but not found (not defined) which mean that the XSLT did the correct conversion.

So the possibilities are :

- There might be a javascript error causing the compilation process to abort before the function definition
- You forgot to put the function definition in a  tag

Make sure you check your javascript error in the console, and comment if this does not solve your issue or if you find any other errors.

Also if this does not fix it, it would help if you could post the converted link ( tag) after the conversion.